# How to change toolstrip overflow Priority

Tags: c#, .net, toolstrip

I want design a componet,it work like win7 explorer's directoy bar,it will add toolstrip item to reflect all directoy,I do this.but when the width less than all componet's width ,it will overflow some button.it first overflow the most left button,nomally it will overflow the most right button,how can I do this?
thk

Comment: Are you doing this in Winforms, or WPF?

Answer (score -1):

I do this in winforms,use the toolstrip